(Handle Polyfill.io Security-Alert) How do you detect if a big npm Codebase uses Polyfill.io somewhere?
Polyfill.io is malicious: https://dev.to/snyk/polyfill-supply-chain-attack-embeds-malware-in-javascript-cdn-assets-55d6
I now need to find it my codebase:
I used: grep -r "polyfill.io" to quickly find the obvious and I checked the Network Traffic of the website.
Network Traffic is however not an exhaustive method to find every polyfill.
How do I efficiently check:

npm subdependencies
dynamically loaded polyfills?
What about other polyfill suppliers like bootcss​.​com bootcdn​.​net & staticfile​.​org? It seems Polyfill.io is not the only one? https://socket.dev/blog/namecheap-takes-down-polyfill-io-service-following-supply-chain-attack


I used https://npmgraph.js.org to check all my deps of my apps

@telion Any luck on this ?

@mahen3d Unfortunately no. I think though that grep -r "polyfill.io" would find a lot in package-lock.json and node-modules too. But I am not sure about the dynamically loaded stuff.

You can use Zaproxy to scan a website for the use of the polyfill[.]io domain. No need to install ZAP, just run a one liner to run the check with a docker container:
docker run -t zaproxy/zap-stable zap.sh -cmd -addoninstall pscanrulesBeta -zapit https://www.example.com/

You can specify as many URLs you like: -zapit https://www.example1.com -zapit http://example2.com/
See https://www.zaproxy.org/blog/2024-06-27-polyfill.io-script-detection/

How does that work with pages that are protected by some authentication system? (meaning you need to login before you see the page)

@telion i haven't tried that but have a look over here: https://adrianhesketh.com/2020/07/07/owasp-baseline-scan-with-basic-auth-in-docker-github-actions/
